# Check if a parameter is already formatted as a date

Tags: perl, mojolicious

How can I check if a parameter is already formatted?

```
$start_date = DateTime::Format::Pg->format_date($start_date);
$end_date = DateTime::Format::Pg->format_date($end_date);
```

To be more specific, I want to check if parameters $start_date and $end_date are formatted before formatting them, because if they are already formatted, I receive an error. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the [Regexp::Common::time](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::time) module for date & time regular expressions would help.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I don't get errors? `perl -MDateTime::Format::Pg -wE'$dt = q(2003-01-16 23:12:01); $obj = DateTime::Format::Pg->parse_datetime($dt); say $obj; $bb = DateTime::Format::Pg->parse_datetime($obj); say $bb'`.  Just prints the exact same, as you'd hope

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly your question, but here is a common piece of code I copy into most of my projects:

```
=head2 format_datetime

  ->search({ date_col => { '>=' => $schema->format_datetime( $myDate ) } })

Utility method to properly format a DateTime according to the current storage
engine.  Optional second argument converts the datetime to a specific time zone
before stringifying.

=cut

sub format_datetime {
   my ($self, $datetime, $time_zone)= @_;

   # Make a datetime if it isn't already
   $datetime= DateTime::Format::Flexible->parse_datetime($datetime)
      unless ref $datetime && ref($datetime)->can('set_time_zone');

   # Force time zone
   $datetime= $datetime->clone->set_time_zone($time_zone)
      if defined $time_zone and $datetime->time_zone ne $time_zone;

   $datetime->set_time_zone('floating'); # prevent datetime formatter from changing time zone
   return $self->storage->datetime_parser->format_datetime($datetime);
}
```

Note that I'm using DBIx::Class, and this method goes into the Schema class.  But anyway, the point is that I check whether the value is a DateTime object, and if not I parse it, then I set the correct time zone (in case it was already a DateTime object with a different timezone than should be stored int he column) and then I use the formatter for the database engine to convert it back to a string.

By using a helper like this, I'm not dependent on a specific date formatter, and I can run my test cases on SQLite.